# How can I access the file in C when the user used the '<' command on the shell?

Tags: c, shell, posix

I am trying to make a program that can process sentences in C in the POSIX environment. Assume that my program's name is "test". If the user entered just "./test", then my program will ask the user to enter some sentences. This one so far is easy.

However, if the user entered "./test < file.txt", the program should get the characters from that txt file. I do not know how I can get the characters of the file in C. I tried something like `file = open(argv[2]);`, but it did not work.

I will really appreciate it if you give me the answer to this question.

Comment: `<` is redirecting the file contents into the standard input of the program. So you would just read it as you would from the console.

Comment: When you have a version of your program that successfully prompts the user for the data, simply try `./test < file.txt` without modification and see what happens

Comment: Since the file is basically input on `stdin` (as if you were typing input yourself), you can read each character with `getchar`, or read in the input as if it were any other file using library functions (`stdin` for functions using FILE *, or `STDIN_FILENO` for those using file-descriptors)

Comment: you dont need to do anything, the shell arranges for the file to be effectively typed in for you ,like a very fast user. You only need to get fancy if the user was to enter `./test file.txt`, this would pass the file name to you

Comment: I suspect what you're *not* telling us is that your interactive program does a whole lot more than just read sentence data from the console (like... menu choices, prompts, etc.) *all* of that needs to be part of the input file if you're using it for stdin redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: If you start your program like

```
./test
```

and you have to type in the input, then exactly the same program will read from file.txt if you start it as

```
./test < file.txt
```

Longer explanation starts here.  (The following explanation is not 100% precise, but shall help to get an understanding what is going on in principle.)

In a C program you can open files with `fopen`.  As a return value, `fopen` gives you a `FILE` pointer.  However, when you start a program under Unix, three `FILE` pointers are already available.  These default `FILE` pointers are stored in variables named `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

Of these, `stdin` can be used to read from, `stdout` and `stderr` can be written to.  And, `stdin` is used as default in several C library calls, like, `gets` or `scanf`.  Similarly, `stdout` is used by default for calls like `printf`.

Now, although they are called `FILE` pointers, they can in fact represent other things than just files.  `stdin` could be a file, but it can also be a console where you can type in stuff.

This latter scenario is what you observe when you start your `test` program from the shell with the command

```
./test
```

In this case, the test process will be started with `stdin` just using the console from the shell from which you started the test program.  Therefore, if in your test program you call, say, `gets()`, then your program will implicitly read from `stdin`, which represents the console input that was inherited from the shell.  Consequently, in this case the user has to provide input by typing it in.

Now let's look at what happens if you start your process from the shell in the following way:

```
./test < file.txt
```

Here, the shell does a bit of extra work before it actually creates your test process.  This is because the `< file.txt` part of your command line is interpreted by the shell - this is not passed as arguments to your program.  Instead, what the shell does is, to open the file.txt and, when the test process is started, hand the opened file.txt over to the process such that in your test process `stdin` is connected to file.txt.

Then, the call to `gets()` in your program will again read from `stdin`, but this time `stdin` is not the console.  This time `stdin` really corresponds to a file, that is, file.txt.

Comment: tldr - @OP doesnt need to do anything, it should just work